# Discord js Voice - AudioResource

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

In the DiscordJs Voice documentation it is stated that AudioPlayer is reusable, so I can create only one instance of it and use it all the time. However, I did not find any mentions about reusability of AudioResource. For example, I want to play the first song in the array:

```
resource = createAudioResource(playlist[0]);
player.play(resource);
```

But if I want to create queue by adding more songs to the playlist, what should I do with the resource? Declare another **resource1**? Or can I do something like:

```
resource.read(playlist[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio resources are not reusable. You will need to simply make another resource

You can however reuse the *variable*, not the resource

```js
resource = createAudioResource(playlist[1])
```